# How to disable DatePicker in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

Now I am working on a project in Angular JS.As of now am a beginner.In my application I have four radio Buttons named week,month,year and Custom.I want to show the Date picker when the custom radio button is clicked only otherwise disable.How do disable Date picker? Have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-disabled="!enableDate" attribute on your date picker where enableDate is the model for the checkbox.